# I can't access an instance variable in an if statement in Java

Tags: java, class, graphics

I am trying to simplify the Javax swing graphics classes in order to make it easier for other people to get into Java graphics, but I am facing a problem with testing it. 
Keep in mind, that I am writing the main method as a user of the code and not the developer. I need answers that will change the code of the class methods and not the main method.

What my main method code is supposed to do is print 'hovering' when the user hovers over the button. However, when I add a SOP statement before the if statement, it works...
The method for the mouse hovering is in the Button class.

Here is my main method code -

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GraphWin win = new GraphWin(1000, 1000, "Graphics Window - Test");
        win.show();

        Button button = new Button(new Point(380, 300), new Point(620, 400));
        button.draw(win);

        enter code herewhile(true) {
            //System.out.println(button.hovering);
            if(button.hovering) {
                System.out.println("hovering");
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is my code for the Button class -

```
public class Button implements MouseListener{
    public JButton button;
    public boolean clicked = false, hovering = false, pressed = false;

    public Button(Point p, Point p2) { //This is the default constructor of the button with only 2 points specified
        this.button = new JButton();
        this.setBounds(p, p2);  
        this.button.addMouseListener(this);
        this.setBorderVisible(false);}

    public Button(Point p, Point p2, String text) { //This constructor requires text to be displayed`enter code here`
        this.button = new JButton(text);
        this.setBounds(p, p2);
        this.button.addMouseListener(this);
        this.setBorderVisible(false);}

    public Button(String icon, Point p, Point p2) { //This constructor sets an Icon for the button
        this.button = new JButton();
        this.setIcon(icon);
        this.setBounds(p, p2);
        this.button.addMouseListener(this);
        this.setBorderVisible(false);}

    public Button(Point p, Point p2, String text, String icon) { //Here, both the text and Icon is specified
        this.button = new JButton(text);
        this.setIcon(icon);
        this.setBounds(p, p2);
        this.button.addMouseListener(this);
        this.setBorderVisible(false);}

    public void draw(GraphWin win) {
        win.window.add(this.button);}
    public void setBounds(Point p, Point p2) {
        this.button.setBounds(p.x, p.y, p2.x - p.x, p2.y - p.y);
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enable) {
        this.button.setEnabled(enable);}
    public void disable() {
        this.button.setEnabled(false);}
    public void enable() {
        this.button.setEnabled(true);
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.button.setBackground(color);}
    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.button.setBackground(Color.decode(color));}

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.button.setText(text);}
    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        File imageCheck = new File(icon);
        if(!imageCheck.exists()) 
            System.out.println("Image file not found!");
        else
            this.button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(icon));
    }

    public void resizeIcon(String icon, int width, int height) {
        Image img = new ImageIcon(icon).getImage();
        img = img.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        this.button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
    }

    public void setCustomMargins(int top, int bottom, int left, int right) {
        this.button.setMargin(new Insets(top, left, bottom, right));}
    public void setMargins(int m) {
        this.button.setMargin(new Insets(m, m, m, m));}

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.button.setToolTipText(label);
    }
    public void setBorderVisible(boolean border) {
        this.button.setBorderPainted(border);}

    public void setOpaque(boolean opaque) {
        this.button.setContentAreaFilled(opaque);}

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        this.hovering = true;
        System.out.println(1);
        }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        this.hovering = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        this.pressed = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        this.pressed = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        this.clicked = true;
        System.out.println(1);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see why the instance variable doesn't work, but just to see if it makes any difference, does it work if you make a getter Button.isHovering()?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Please describe the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of thing is usually to do with threading.

Events in Swing are dispatched on the AWT Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). In order to be thread-safe, practically everything dealing with Swing/AWT should be done on the EDT.

In your case, there is no kind of locking between the variable being set and read. Adding a `println` causes a pause (with all sorts of memory barriers or whatnot) that happens to allow the program to run in the desired sequence.

You've probably seen `main` methods written to pass execution straight over to the AWT.

```
class MyGUI {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(MyGUI::go);
    }
    private static void go() {
        ...
```

It might be better to supply the main class yourself, implemented such that it takes the application class as an argument and passes execution on once everything is setup. Whilst traditionally command lines use a `main` static method/function, everywhere else subtypes: Applets, Servlets, etc.

Comment: I tried your method, it worked but is a little hard for newer programmers to use who are the ones using my code. I tried using Thread.sleep(10); and it works as well. Will that make a difference?

Comment: @BhavyeMathur If you try fixing threading problems by inserting `sleep`s you are just storing up more difficult surprises. Bung everything in one thread and it's simple again.

Answer (score 0):

best approach would be to use a `isHovering()` method but educated guess on the behavior inside a `while(true)` with or without a Sysout might be related to a compiler optimisation. Might be fixed by putting the hovering variable as `transient`

Comment: `volatile` (`transient` is for serialisation persistence).